# Execute a function after CController->render and CController->processOutput

Tags: php, yii

I want execute a static method after `CController->processOutput` (after some javascript code has run in browser).

How can do it?

Comment: There is absolutely no way to predict what happens in the browser. If you want to do something after JavaScript runs, you have to trigger that something on the client after that JS has run.

Comment: If you want to achieve this, you have to execute the other method with AJAX, since there is no way (like Jon said) you can execute PHP after it rendered to the browser.